# Share button not showing apps (Swift/Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make my app share a PDF. But when the share button is pressed and the shares show, there is nothing to choose from. Only "[...] More" which gives no options. Can anyone help me out? My code is:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class PDF1: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Brewolution A Bunnys Tale - Påske 2012", ofType: ".pdf")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        webView.load(request)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func sharePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.webView], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

Comment: So there is no way for attaching the PDF in the email application and send it out as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a UI component like `self.webview` as you currently do , only text,images ,,,, etc where there are extensions from other apps that support such item types and will be shown immediately

Comment: And you also can't share a file from inside your bundle.

Comment: So there is no way for attaching the PDF in the email application and send it out as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let shareText = "PDF URL add"
    if let image = UIImage(named: "share.png") {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, image], applicationActivities: [])
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in your code. Posting just the code is not a quality answer. Explain what it does.